# como recorrer y anidar un arreglo proveniente de un procedimiento almacenado en laravel

Tags: laravel, stored-procedure, foreach, laravel-4

Estimado tengo un procedimiento almacenado que me trae un arreglo

```
$sql =  "CALL APP_CATEGORIAS";
$cat_productos = DB::select($sql);
```

Este arreglo contiene varios productos cada uno con sus categorías, cual es la mejor opcion para recorrerlo y anidar los productos según su categoría ?

el arreglo se ve así

```
array:80 [
  0 => {#664
    +"COD_CAT": 1000999
    +"NOM_CAT": "Sugeridos para ti"
    +"ID": 9197
    +"SKU": "23777"
    +"NOMBRE": "producto 10"
    +"STOCK": 32,0
    +"PRECIO_NORMAL": 14990,0
    +"PRECIO_SOCIO": 13490,0
    +"IMAGE_LINK": "23777.jpg"
  }
  1 => {#667
    +"COD_CAT": 1000999
    +"NOM_CAT": "Sugeridos para ti"
    +"ID": 9953
    +"SKU": "24907"
    +"NOMBRE": "producto 5"
    +"STOCK": 238,0
    +"PRECIO_NORMAL": 15990,0
    +"PRECIO_SOCIO": 13900,0
    +"IMAGE_LINK": "24907.jpg"
  }
```

y luego los muestro por

return response()->json($cat_productos);

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadir el array a una collection y utilizar sus funciones

```
$collection = collect($array);

$grouped = $collection->groupBy('COD_CAT');
dd($grouped);
```